# How to automate an IME application in android?

Tags: android, automation

I'm trying to automate an IME application in android. The actual scenario is that,we need to open some kind of default editor on the phone(Email, Gmail,Message)and try to generate touch event on the IME(Input method editors).

I had even tried it out with robotium tool to pass the key events, but couldn't accomplish the actual scenario.

So please help me out in solving this problem I really want to know whether their is any way to stimulate touch events on the IME an perform the click events.

Thanks and Regards

Rajesh Samson.

Comment: Is this for use from a test project (e.g., one using instrumentation)?

Comment: Yes we need to work from the test project